# With the GitHub GraphQL API, how do I get the size of a file for commits over time?

Tags: git, graphql, github-api

I want to chart the size of a file over time for a project. To do that, I need the size of the file for the last 100 commits (or at least those commits that change it).

How do I get that data with the GitHub GraphQL API?

I can get the history of a project:

```graphql
{ 
  repository(owner:"someOwner", name:"some-Repo") {
    defaultBranchRef{
      target {
        ...on Commit{
          history(first:100, path: "some/file/path") {
            nodes {
              committedDate
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I can get the size of the file on the HEAD of master:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner:"someOwner", name:"some-Repo" ) {
    object(expression: "master:some/file/path") {
      ...on Blob {
        byteSize
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

But the following doesn't work:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "someOwner", name: "some-Repo") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 100, path: "some/file/path") {
            nodes {
              committedDate
              repository {
                object(expression: "master:some/file/path") {
                  ... on Blob {
                    byteSize
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It gives me the *current* file size every time, instead of the file size for the given commit.

Is it *possible* to get that data via the GraphQL API in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get the `tree` from the `commit` result and list file entries. This would work but would return all files for that commit. For example:

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "media-optimizer") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 100, path: "cloudformation.yml") {
            nodes {
              oid
              tree {
                entries {
                  name
                  object {
                    ...on Blob {
                      byteSize
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could then filter the correct file in the result like :

```bash
TOKEN=[YOUR TOKEN]
REPO_OWNER=bertrandmartel
REPO_NAME=media-optimizer
FILE_PATH=cloudformation.yml

curl -s -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" \
     -H  "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{repository(owner: \"'"$REPO_OWNER"'\", name: \"'"$REPO_NAME"'\") { defaultBranchRef {target {... on Commit {history(first: 100, path: \"'"$FILE_PATH"'\") {nodes {committedDate tree {entries {name object {...on Blob {byteSize}}}}}}}}}}}"
      }' https://api.github.com/graphql | jq '.data.repository.defaultBranchRef.target.history.nodes[] | 
        {
            date:.committedDate, 
            size: .tree.entries[] | select(.name=="'"$FILE_PATH"'") | .object.byteSize
        }'
```

which would output :

```
{
  "date": "2020-01-29T17:30:58Z",
  "size": 8408
}
{
  "date": "2020-01-29T16:43:00Z",
  "size": 8030
}
{
  "date": "2020-01-29T01:50:31Z",
  "size": 7601
}
```

Another way without listing all fields would be to perform 2 requests, the first listing all commit ID. The second request being created dynamically using [aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to perform multiple `object(expression: "OID:some/file/path")` as you suggested

First request: query date and oid :

```graphql
query getCommitOid {
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "media-optimizer") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 100, path: "cloudformation.yml") {
            nodes {
              committedDate
              oid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second request : build aliases for each commit (here for 3 commits):

```graphql
query getByteSize {
  repository(owner: "bertrandmartel", name: "media-optimizer") {
    commit1: object(expression: "310fe12a847549ac33096d1f7301ea0a968c638c:cloudformation.yml") {
      ... on Blob {
        byteSize
      }
    }
    commit2: object(expression: "9eb80883322420fc1bf51b924c2c56ec8af8b109:cloudformation.yml") {
      ... on Blob {
        byteSize
      }
    }
    commit3: object(expression: "53172d2c7d439d7d97935c422c5b853a7cc5458d:cloudformation.yml") {
      ... on Blob {
        byteSize
      }
    }
  }
}
```